# Extending ArrayList of classes implementing certain classes containing generics doesn't work?

Tags: java, class, generics, arraylist

Someone knows why this doesn't work?

```
public class ArrayList<E extends EXTDBinterface<T>> 
    extends java.util.ArrayList<E> implements List<E>,
    RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {}
```

Eclipse complains about T not being resolved to a type... Is it impossible to extend the ArrayList class for types extending `EXTDBinterface<T>`? The point is I would like to use `T` inside the class, but sadly only this works:

```
public class ArrayList<E extends EXTDBinterface> 
    extends java.util.ArrayList<E> implements List<E>,
    RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {}
```

but then how to get the generic type `T` of `EXTDBinterface` at runtime...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First doesn't work cause you didn't set type `T`.
Also you don't need to extend and implement all stuff again cause ArrayList has had this yet.
Write, for example:

```
class ArrayList<T,E extends EXTDBinterface<T>> 
extends java.util.ArrayList<E>{}
```

Comment: Yes thanks for the additional correction of removing the implements! This is the correct answer, but don't know if you or [GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1034737/gangnamstyleoverflowerror) was first ^^

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the generic type T of EXTDBinterface at runtime

You can't do that given that Java makes use of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). If you need the actual type, then you'll have to pass that in (normally as a `Class`-typed parameter)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, I think you're right... Checking out crazy solutions here ^^. None seem to work...

Comment: Check out [bellum](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1506264/bellum)'s answer. Seems to do what I want!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `T` as the type argument for the class

```
public class ArrayList<T, E extends EXTDBinterface<T>> 
    extends java.util.ArrayList<E> implements List<E>,
    RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Eclipse complains even more with this ^^. But would it compile?

Comment: umm, i compiled fine for me, what does eclipse complain about ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, after your edit it works! But did you edit before or after [bellum](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1506264/bellum)'s answer? Cause it says 43 minutes both ^^